# How to return enum's values marked with custom attribute using C#

Tags: c#, enums, custom-attributes

I have an enum with some members marked by custom attribute like:

```
public enum VideoClipTypeEnum : int
{
    Exhibitions = 1,

    TV = 2,

    [ClipTypeDisplayAttribute(false)]
    Content = 3
}
```

My attribute is:

```
public class ClipTypeDisplayAttribute : DescriptionAttribute
    {
        #region Private Variables

        private bool _treatAsPublicType;

        #endregion

        #region Ctor

        public ClipTypeDisplayAttribute(bool treatAsPublicType)
        {
            _treatAsPublicType = treatAsPublicType;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Props

        public bool TreatAsPublicType
        {
            get
            {
                return _treatAsPublicType;
            }
            set
            {
                _treatAsPublicType = value;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

What is the best way of getting the values of members marked with my custom attribute into List?

Comment: Can you be more specific? There are no fields in your example - are you talking about enum members? Do you want to receive only enum members, that are marked with attributes?

Comment: Exactly! Members... sorry for that trap )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
var values = 
    from f in typeof(VideoClipTypeEnum).GetFields()
    let attr = f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ClipTypeDisplayAttribute))
                .Cast<ClipTypeDisplayAttribute>()
                .FirstOrDefault()
    where attr != null
    select f;
```

This will actually return the `FieldInfo` for the enum value. To get the raw value, try this.

```
var values = 
    ... // same as above
    select (VideoClipTypeEnum)f.GetValue(null);
```

If you also want to filter by some property of the attribute, you can do that too. Like this

```
var values = 
    ... // same as above
    where attr != null && attr.TreatAsPublicType
    ... // same as above
```

*Note*: This works because enum values (e.g. `VideoClipTypeEnum.TV`) are actually implemented as static, constant fields of the `VideoClipTypeEnum` internally.

To get a `List<int>` use this

```
var values = 
    (from f in typeof(VideoClipTypeEnum).GetFields()
     let attr = f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ClipTypeDisplayAttribute))
                 .Cast<ClipTypeDisplayAttribute>()
                 .FirstOrDefault()
     where attr != null
     select (int)f.GetValue(null))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I need to get the List<int> of values? I need that list to filter the videoClips in my repo.

Comment: [`GetCustomAttributes<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194330.aspx) is an extension that wraps up two of your steps and makes it more readable, IMO.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever seems like that's only available in 4.5, but good to know.